# how do I know if two html elements (div, map or other) border?

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I am creating a dynamic version of [Risiko game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RisiKo!) and I have following question.
Is there a way to make that automatically with html tags (map, div or others)? Also using javascript how I can find if two elements are adjacent?

Comment: call getBoundingClientRect() and see if the values are adjacent.

Answer (score 0):

i will show with jquery.

for example :

```
if( $('element').css('border-width') > 0)
```

if you have more than 1 elements in same class use ID or just create another class. you can even do it like that :

```
for ( i = 0 ; i < $('element').length ; i++)
{
  if( $('element').eq(i).css('border-width') > 0)
  //create an array and push 0 and 1 s to that . could be helpful sometimes
}
```

Comment: It sounded to me as if the OP was asking about two elements that border each other i.e. are adjacent, otherwise why mention two elements?

Comment: yes it could also be nice question to ask . you can just find minus offsets and find the distance. but how you even know they are in same row? what if you will open the website in a phone or tablet? ok maybe it is computer. u just say it like that: find left offset of each. and compare to see which is in left and which is in right. then which is left er just + its own width and borders (if exist ) to that and - offset the right er element. this would be wrong in too many situations :D